# Multi threading and typecast in js frameworks

Tags: javascript, multithreading

I am new to js frameworks. So i am not sure whether angular, react, backbone, knockout, ember and batman.js support multi threading. Can anyone please explain. Also please explain typecasting of all the above frameworks.

Comment: This is too broad to be answered in one answer.

Comment: Can i get yes/no answer for multi threading support on angular, react, backbone, knockout, ember and batman.js frameworks pls?

Comment: `Can anyone please explain` and `. Also please explain typecasting of all the above frameworks` says otherwise.